# Equivalent of javax.ws.rs NameBinding in Micronaut?

Tags: java, java-11, micronaut

I am working on porting an old HTTP server to Micronaut and I am stuck trying to port an authorization filter that used the `javax.ws.rs` `NameBinding` annotation to a Micronaut HTTP server filter. 90% of my endpoints/controllers use the `NameBinding` annotation I have so using the standard Micronaut HTTP server filter would be difficult.

One code smelly thought was to create a filter accepting all api endpoints (ie. `@Filter("/**")`) and then maybe storing a list of all the paths that don't require authorization and comparing that against the requested path.

Another hack I attempted to was to try and derive the target method with reflections through the request/chain but it seems that target method is held in an `@Internal` class which leads me to believe I should not be reflecting on the method from a filter. If I was able to reflect on the target method from a filter I could look for my old annotation and filter on that.

In general are there any guiding principles for providing filters to a large subset of controllers/methods excluding a handful, for example an inverse filter pattern (although this would also not be ideal)?

Is there any way in micronaut to manually control the injection of filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a fine grained control over your endpoints, I'll go for [micronaut AOP](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#aop)

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Around
@Type(AuthenticatedInterceptor.class)
public @interface Authenticated {
}
```

and the interceptor coresponding

```java
@Singleton
public class AuthenticatedInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public Object intercept(MethodInvocationContext<Object, Object> context) {
        final var authHeader = ServerRequestContext.currentRequest()
                .map(HttpMessage::getHeaders)
                .flatMap(HttpHeaders::getAuthorization)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("no header"));

        validate(authHeader);

        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

then you'll have to add `@Authenticated` on each methods that need to be authenticated.

### UPDATE

Micronaut security provides it's [own](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/index.html#secured) `@Secured` annotation.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. I have to do something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66808543/2291305