# How to get Authorization header from an MethodInterpcetor on micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut

Before everything I tried this two solution but didn't work for me
[Equivalent of javax.ws.rs NameBinding in Micronaut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840896/equivalent-of-javax-ws-rs-namebinding-in-micronaut)
https://blogs.ashrithgn.com/custom-annotation-to-handle-authorisation-in-micronaut-aop-tutorial/

In my application I have to get a string in the Authorization header and then decode it from base64 and the json transform it into a POJO. Certainly the string is a jwt and I need to decode the public part of the json to get a data from a field.
Technically speaking a client will forward the header to me to take it, decode it and extract the data. (It's very bad practice but that's what I have to do).

For this I am using micronaut 2.4.1 and this is my code:

Interceptor:

```
public class HeadInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor<Object, Object> {
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object intercept(MethodInvocationContext<Object, Object> context) {

        Request request = (Request) context.getParameterValueMap().get("request");
        // Where do i get Authorization header?
        // i.e String token = (String) context.getParameterValueMap().get("Authorization");
        String token = "eyJhdWQiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiaXNzIjoidGVzdCIsInN1YiI6InRlc3QiLCJleHAiOjExMTExMTEsImlhdCI6MTExMTExMTEsImRhdGEiOiJ0ZXN0In0=";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Info info = mapper.readValue(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(token)), Info.class);
        request.setData(info.getSub().toUpperCase());

        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller("/main")
public class MainController {

    @Post
    @Head
    public Single<Response> index(@Body @Valid Request request) {
        return Single.just(
                Response.builder()
                        .message(String.format("%s-%s", request.getData(), request.getInfo()))
                        .build()
        );
    }
}
```

Here's a sample app https://github.com/j1cs/micronaut-jacksonxml-error
(ignore the name is for other issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation, the header cannot be shown in the interceptor because your `index` method doesn't receive it as a parameter.

So, if you add it as a parameter as below:

```
...
@Post
@Head
public Single<Response> index(@Body @Valid Request request, @Header("Authorization") String authorizationHeader) {
    return Single.just(
            Response.builder()
                    .message(String.format("%s-%s", request.getData(), request.getInfo()))
                    .build()
    );
}
...
```

Then, you can retrieve it in the `intercept` method via `getParameterValues()`. Basically, it will be the second argument.

```
...
@SneakyThrows
@Override
public Object intercept(MethodInvocationContext<Object, Object> context) {
    ...
    String token = (String) context.getParameterValues()[1];
    ...
}
...
```

## Update

Since you want your `Request` to contain both body and header, I edited the solution a bit. Basically, the header is added as a member variable to `Request` as below:

```
public class Request {
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String info;
    private String data;

    @Header("Authorization")
    String authorizationHeader;
}
```

Then, use `@RequestBean` rather than a `@Body` annotation on your `Request` parameter:

```
...
@Post
@Head
public Single<Response> index(@RequestBean @Valid Request request) {
    return Single.just(
            Response.builder()
                    .message(String.format("%s-%s", request.getData(), request.getInfo()))
                    .build()
    );
}
...
```

Finally, you can access the header easily in your `intercept()` method as follows:

```
@SneakyThrows
@Override
public Object intercept(MethodInvocationContext<Object, Object> context) {
    ...   
    Request request = (Request) context.getParameterValueMap().get("request");
    String token = request.authorizationHeader;
    ...
}
```

**I created a pull request for this change [here](https://github.com/j1cs/micronaut-jacksonxml-error/pull/1), so you can check how it** works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to address the problem, you may first break the problem into parts.

Part 1: How to get arbitrary header (or list all headers)?

Try to use `request.getHeaders()` [doc](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/HttpMessage.html#getHeaders--).

Part 2: How to get the header named `Authorization` ?

Use the way in part 1. In addition, be careful about the *case*. For example, is `Authorization` the same as `authorization`?

---

#### Method 2:

In controller (https://github.com/j1cs/micronaut-jacksonxml-error/blob/master/src/main/java/me/jics/MainController.java):

```
public Single<Response> index(@Body Request request, @Header('Authorization') String authorization) {
...
}
```

p.s. the "Header" annotation's doc is here: https://docs.micronaut.io/2.0.1/api/io/micronaut/http/annotation/Header.html

In interceptor:

```
...
String token = context.getParameterValueMap().get("authorization");
...
```

**Why the code looks like this**:

1. Firstly get the auth header you want using parameter injection.
2. Secondly, recall the fundamental concepts of AOP / AspectJ (which your interceptor class uses). Inside your interceptor, you intercept a method (in your case, the `index` method in controller. Thus, you can happily get the parameters of that method. In the code above, just the `authorization` parameter.

Please tell me if you are stuck on somewhere (and paste the code and the outputs).